# Alternative scaling methods to log

Tags: data-visualization, data-transformation, logarithm

I have data (as below). When I plot, the details of 0-10 are lost. So I scale it using a log function and then it seems that detail is lost throughout. Is there another scaling method that would work better?

```
0   85059     
1   169483    
2   258009    
3   351540    
4   470079    
5   703145    
6   1275796   
7   2349113   
8   5010993   
9   13406570  
10  44575314  
11  141425918  
12  512397968  
13  1692690034  
14  5580227267
```

Comment: Do you just want to plot it? Can you say more about what you want from a plot of your data / what detail you want to preserve? Subsequent to plotting, are you intending to analyze these data somehow? If so, how? What is your end goal?

Comment: Yes, just want to plot it. The thing I don't like about the log plot is that it it essentially a straight line, not showing any curve at all. It may be that nothing can be done, just wanted to check with experts.

Comment: That the data form a straight line when plotted using the log transformation strikes me as an important fact here. Often, discovering something like that is the point of plotting / data exploration.

Comment: I see your point. I guess the difficulty there is that the people viewing this won't understand what a log transformation is.

Comment: What are these data? The undulate a bit like a sine wave.